TapGestureRecognizer on .NET MAUI
I have a very simple, single paged .NET MAUI piece of code. The XAML contains 4 Labels and 1 Image. The 1st Label has a TapGestureRecognizer with a Tapped event. When tapped, the 2nd Label Text changes. This works fine.
My 3rd Label similarly has a TapGestureRecognizer, but this time uses a Command which links back to the code behind and when tapped, changes the Text in the 4th Label.
If the Image is tapped, the 4th Label Text changes.
That's the theory. The reality is that only the TapGestureRecognizer with the Tapped event does anything.
My XAML looks like this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="TapGestureRecognizer.MainPage" >
    <VerticalStackLayout Padding="8" HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <Label Text="Please tap me" FontSize="16" Margin="0,8">
            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Tapped="LabelTapped" />
            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
        </Label>
        <Label Text="" Padding="8" TextColor="Red" x:Name="uiLabel" />
        <Label Text="Please tap me here" FontSize="16" Margin="0,8">
            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Command="{Binding LabelTappedCommand}" />   
            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
        </Label>
        <Label Text="" Padding="8" TextColor="Red" x:Name="uiLabel2" />
        <Image Source="dotnet_bot.png" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100">
             <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                 <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Command="{Binding LabelTappedCommand}" />
             </Image.GestureRecognizers>
         </Image>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>

The code behind is this
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace TapGestureRecognizer;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    bool _selected = false;
    bool _otherSelected = false;
    public ICommand LabelTappedCommand { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
        LabelTappedCommand = new Command(() =>
        {
            uiLabel2.Text = !_otherSelected ? "Wax on" : "Wax off";
            _otherSelected = !_otherSelected;
        });
    }

    void LabelTapped(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
    {
        uiLabel.Text = !_selected ? "Hello" : "Goodbye";
        _selected = !_selected;
    }

    void OnTapped()
    {
        uiLabel2.Text = !_otherSelected ? "Wax on" : "Wax off";
        _otherSelected = !_otherSelected;
    }
}

The OnTapped method is there as I changed the lambda in case that was the issue - the lambda previously called the OnTapped method.
Does anyone have any insights on why the 3rd Label or the Image is not firing the code behind?

have you verified that the command is called in the debugger?  If it is, you might need to use MainThread to force the UI update on the correct thread.  Or use data binding

It looks like the code is not being hit, but for the life of me, I can't see why this would be the case as the BindingContext is set and nothing is showing in the XAML of the commands not being found

Try assigning the BindingContext after you assign the commands

The reason it does not work is because your command has no reference of where to look for the Binding
try this

<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Name="this"
         x:Class="TapGestureRecognizer.MainPage" >
    <VerticalStackLayout Padding="8" HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <Label Text="Please tap me" FontSize="16" Margin="0,8">
            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Tapped="LabelTapped" />
            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
        </Label>
        <Label Text="" Padding="8" TextColor="Red" x:Name="uiLabel" />
        <Label Text="Please tap me here" FontSize="16" Margin="0,8">
            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Command="{Binding LabelTappedCommand, Source={x:Reference this}}" />   
            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
        </Label>
        <Label Text="" Padding="8" TextColor="Red" x:Name="uiLabel2" />
        <Image Source="dotnet_bot.png" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100">
             <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                 <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Command="{Binding LabelTappedCommand, Source={x:Reference this}}" />
             </Image.GestureRecognizers>
         </Image>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>



Does the command get called?

He assigns the BindingContext in the page constructor

Just as Json mentioned, we should set the  BindingContext = this; after assigning  command LabelTappedCommand .
The correct code should be as follows:
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //BindingContext = this;

    LabelTappedCommand = new Command(() =>
    {
        uiLabel2.Text = !_otherSelected ? "Wax on" : "Wax off";
        _otherSelected = !_otherSelected;
    });

   //set BindingContext here
   BindingContext = this;
}

